# Why does this jquery css not work?

Tags: jquery, css

when I have this HTML:

```
<div id="map">
  <div class="elem">
    hey1
  </div>
   <div class="elem">
    hey2
  </div>
   <div class="elem">
    hey3
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var elems = $('#map .elem');
elems[1].css("color", "white");
```

This is somehow wrong, but I don´t get how to do it right?

I don´t get it, because this works:

```
var map = $('#map');
map.css("background", "red");
```

Here´s a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/y596ynsb/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function `css()` is a jQuery variable, it is applicable only for jQuery objects. 
Using array access `[]`, it gets a DOM element, which does not have the jQuery function `css()`.

So you need to use [**`eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), in order to get the nth element as a jQuery object.

```
elems.eq(0).css("color", "white");
```

```js
var map = $('#map');
map.css("background", "red");
var elems = $('#map .elem');
elems.eq(0).css("color", "white");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map">
  <div class="elem">hey1</div>
  <div class="elem">hey2</div>
  <div class="elem">hey3</div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/y596ynsb/1/)

Comment: is using `.eq(0)` the same as wrapping `$(elems)` in a jQuery selector? Allowing `elems` to have access the to jQuery css function.

Comment: @JoshSpears You don't need to use `$(elems)` because `elems` is already a jquery object.

Comment: Well i mean `elems[1]` returns a dom object right? So wrapping that in a `$()` jQuery selector would be the same as `.eq(0)`? Or no.

Comment: That's true, but if you did `$(elems[1])` you are retrieving a DOMElement from a jQuery object to turn that back in to a jQuery object, which is beyond pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:nth-child()` selector to do that. Updated [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/y596ynsb/2/)

```js
$(function() {
  var map = $('#map');
  map.css("background", "red");

  var elems = $('#map .elem:nth-child(1)');
  elems.css("color", "white");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map">
  <div class="elem">
    hey1
  </div>
  <div class="elem">
    hey2
  </div>
  <div class="elem">
    hey3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is setting some styling rules on the a specific element by its index, then there's no need to do that in JS at all. CSS was designed for this purpose; specifically the `nth-child()` selector:

```css
#map .elem:nth-child(1) {
  color: red; /* used red here as white would be invisible in SO :) */
}
```

```html
<div id="map">
  <div class="elem">
    hey1
  </div>
  <div class="elem">
    hey2
  </div>
  <div class="elem">
    hey3
  </div>
</div>
```

If you absolutely had to do this in JS, because some business logic decides which element should get highlighted for example, then you should use the `eq()` method to select the required element and return it in a jQuery object. You should also apply a CSS class to it, as you should avoid having any inline styling in your HTML or JS code where possible.

```js
$('#map .elem').eq(0).addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map">
  <div class="elem">
    hey1
  </div>
  <div class="elem">
    hey2
  </div>
  <div class="elem">
    hey3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this line of your code:

```
var elems = $('#map .elem');
elems.eq(0).css("color", "white");
```